# Expect not correctly setting Vagrant passwd

Tags: bash, expect

I am running a sub expect script from a bash script that provisions a vms here, and am not getting my expected result (ala, password = foo). Here is what I'm running, help appr

```
## Create generic(s) for Vagrant
groupadd admin
useradd -G admin vagrant
/usr/bin/expect -dc 'expect { 
  eval spawn passwd vagrant 
  set prompt ":|#|\\\$"                       ## use correct prompt
  interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return    ## must be done twice due to week passwd
  send "vagrant\r"
  interact -o -nobuffer -re $prompt return
  send "vagrant\r"
  interact
}'
```

Here is a screen cap of the debug

[image: Screen Cap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `expect` code can be optimized with the use of `exp_continue` as shown below.

```
PASSWD=$(expect -c '
  log_user 0
  proc abort {} {
    puts "Error with setting password?"
    exit 1
  }
  spawn passwd vagrant
  expect {
    password:        { send "vagrant\r";exp_continue }
    default          abort
    eof
  }
  puts "User Vagrant has had password set..."
')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with

```
PASSWD=$(expect -c '
  log_user 0
  proc abort {} {
    puts "Error with setting password?"
    exit 1
  }
  spawn passwd vagrant
  expect {
    password:        { send "vagrant\r" }
    default          abort
  }
  expect {
    password:        { send "vagrant\r" }
    default          abort
    eof
  }
  puts "User Vagrant has had password set..."
')
```